# react-native build failed, getting Error: app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

i get this error when i try to build release version using gradlew assembleRelease oe any other command.

Here's full error:

```
> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
'[node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseExpoManifest'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
920 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 903 up-to-date
```

i'm getting node error but i have node installed, now sure why i'm unable to build. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I also get this error. This commit fixes the bug, apply it manually until it is applied in a new version of expo-updates:
https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/24116

Before applying the above commit, update the expo-updates lib to version 0.18.12

Comment: i just removed expo-updates and it worked

Comment: @gulshan_____ removed as in just uninstalled expo-updates and removed all code where it was used ?

Comment: @PedroPaulo its resolved how ? by removing the expo-updates or with the github link ?

Comment: @dholu Applying the guidelines in my comment it started to compile just fine. But removing expo-updates also solved the problem. If you are not going to use expo-updates, better remove it.

Comment: Removing expo-updates worked for me.